# Exchange 2010 message tracking log to database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I have Exchange 2010 running and i need to track all the emails. I have made a program to get emails from Exchange and do what i need, but the problem is, that if user deletes email or moves it to archive, i can't access it.
Is there a way to make Exchange to write message tracking log to database? Or at least a way to launch program when email is received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is good that you wrote an application to do this, but you shouldn't had. Exchange already has Mailbox Audit Logging features and that what you should use, see [Understanding Mailbox Audit Logging](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff459237.aspx). You can configure [Journaling](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998649) which automatically records all incomming and outgoing mails. This is a complex topic and rather than re-invent the wheel, I recommend reading about what is already available.

Comment: This is awesome. Journaling is exactly what i need. Except one problem: i can get all emails to one mailbox, but there is only `sender, subject, recipient and message-id`. How would it be possible to get email `body` also?

Comment: I'm not an Exchange expert unfortunately. Perhaps someone more knowleadgeable can answer, I suggets you post a new question with a title that clearly suggest the issue so that it attracts the right pair of eyes.